# How can I count the number of events in a given interval?

Tags: java, algorithm, counter, performancecounter

I need to know how frequency different events occur. For example how many HTTP requests have occurred in the last 15 minutes. Because there can be a large count of events (millions) this must be use a limited amount of memory.

It there any util class in Java that can do this?

How can I implement this self in Java?

Theoretical usage code can look like:

```
FrequencyCounter counter = new FrequencyCounter( 15, TimeUnit.Minutes );
...
counter.add();
...
int count = counter.getCount();
```

Edit: It must be a real time value which can changed thousand times the minute and will be query thousands times the minute. That a database or file based solution are not possible.

Comment: Do you have any other limitations? (Concurrency wise?)

Comment: If your applications output some logs and I am sure it does, why don't you have another process (that could actually be located on another server, as long as it as access to the log files) analyse those logs to extract this information? If you do not need to have this information in real time you could imagine to trigger a kind of batch job that would do the computation one time per day, or a couple of times per day when the load is not high (e.g. during the night etc)

Comment: You could have a counter that resets at midnight and enter the number of requests each minute in a db. Then all you need to count is the fraction of the minute at the start and end of the interval the rest can be calculated. This could be optimized further by storing the count every x seconds too and you can calculate the count with minutes and the smaller interval, so you only have to count x seconds.

Comment: @Allan it must be real time. Sorry that I forget to write it.

Comment: @GalAbra Yes, concurrency / thread safe is needed. But I think a synchronized should solve this. It must not be high concurrency.

Comment: You mean how many events occur in the **next** 15 minutes or occur**ed** in the last 15 minutes?

Comment: @maraca I want the events from the past and not from the future. I have fix the grammatical error in the text. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my implementation of such a counter. The memory usage with the default precision is fewer as 100 bytes. The memory usage is independent of the event count.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

/**
 * A counter that counts events within the past time interval. All events that occurred before this interval will be
 * removed from the counter.
 */
public class FrequencyCounter {

    private final long          monitoringInterval;

    private final int[]         details;

    private final AtomicInteger currentCount = new AtomicInteger();

    private long                startInterval;

    private int                 total;

    /**
     * Create a new instance of the counter for the given interval.
     * 
     * @param interval the time to monitor/count the events.
     * @param unit the time unit of the {@code interval} argument
     */
    FrequencyCounter( long interval, TimeUnit unit ) {
        this( interval, unit, 16 );
    }

    /**
     * Create a new instance of the counter for the given interval.
     * 
     * @param interval the time to monitor/count the events.
     * @param unit the time unit of the {@code interval} argument
     * @param precision the count of time slices for the for the measurement
     */
    FrequencyCounter( long interval, TimeUnit unit, int precision ) {
        monitoringInterval = unit.toMillis( interval );
        if( monitoringInterval <= 0 ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Interval mus be a positive value:" + interval );
        }
        details = new int[precision];
        startInterval = System.currentTimeMillis() - monitoringInterval;
    }

    /**
     * Count a single event.
     */
    public void increment() {
        checkInterval( System.currentTimeMillis() );
        currentCount.incrementAndGet();
    }

    /**
     * Get the current value of the counter.
     * 
     * @return the counter value
     */
    public int getCount() {
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        checkInterval( currentTime );
        long diff = currentTime - startInterval - monitoringInterval;

        double partFactor = (diff * details.length / (double)monitoringInterval);
        int part = (int)(details[0] * partFactor);
        return total + currentCount.get() - part;
    }

    /**
     * Check the interval of the detail counters and move the interval if needed.
     * 
     * @param time the current time
     */
    private void checkInterval( final long time ) {
        if( (time - startInterval - monitoringInterval) > monitoringInterval / details.length ) {
            synchronized( details ) {
                long detailInterval = monitoringInterval / details.length;
                while( (time - startInterval - monitoringInterval) > detailInterval ) {
                    int currentValue = currentCount.getAndSet( 0 );
                    if( (total | currentValue) == 0 ) {
                        // for the case that the counter was not used for a long time
                        startInterval = time - monitoringInterval;
                        return;
                    }
                    int size = details.length - 1;
                    total += currentValue - details[0];
                    System.arraycopy( details, 1, details, 0, size );
                    details[size] = currentValue;
                    startInterval += detailInterval;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think to implement this is using another "time counting" thread.
If you're concerned about the amount of memory, you can add a threshold for the size of `eventsCounter` (`Integer.MAX_VALUE` seems like the natural choice).

Here's an example for an implementation, that is also thread-safe:

```
public class FrequencyCounter {

    private AtomicInteger eventsCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private int timeCounter;
    private boolean active;

    public FrequencyCounter(int timeInSeconds) {
        timeCounter = timeInSeconds;
        active = true;
    }

    // Call this method whenever an interesting event occurs
    public int add() {
        if(active) {
            int current;
            do {
                current = eventsCounter.get();
            } while (eventsCounter.compareAndSet(current, current + 1));

            return current + 1;
        }
        else return -1;
    }

    // Get current number of events
    public int getCount() {
        return eventsCounter.get();
    }

    // Start the FrequencyCounter
    public void run() {
        Thread timer = new Thread(() -> {
            while(timeCounter > 0) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                timeCounter --;
            }
            active = false;
        });
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a scheduled executor service.

```
class TimedValue{
    int startValue;
    int finishedValue;
    TimedValue(int start){
         startValue = start;
    }
}

List<TimedValue> intervals = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

//then when starting a measurement.
TimeValue value = new TimedValue();

//set the start value. 
Callable<TimedValue> callable = ()->{
    //performs the task.

    value.setValueAtFinish(getCount());
    return value;
}

ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);

ScheduledFuture<TimedValue> future = executor.schedule(
                                       callable, 
                                       TimeUnit.MINUTES, 
                                       15);

executor.schedule(()->itervals.add(
                        future.get(),
                        TimeUnit.MINUTES, 
                        future.getDelay(TimeUnit.MINUTES
                      );
```

This is a bit of a complicated method.

I would probably just have a `List<LoggedValues>` and accumulate values in that list at a fixed rate. Then it could be inspected whenever you want to know an intervals.